# Calculating tan to power -1

Tags: trigonometry

I have an equation of the form 
$$
a = \tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}
$$

is this the same as

$$
a = \frac{1}{\tan\,\left.y\middle/x\right.}
$$

It has been over 20 years since doing math and I cannot find any answers on google.

Comment: $\tan^{-1}$ often refers to [$\arctan$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).

Comment: Maybe the $^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $\tan$, i.e., $\arctan$.

Comment: Usually, $\tan^{-1}$ means $\arctan$, while $\frac{1}{\tan \varphi} = \cot \varphi$.

Comment: In fact, certainly it means $\arctan$ here given that its argument is $\frac{y}{x}$, so that $a$ denotes the argument of the point $(x, y)$, $y > 0$, or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some confusion in this area. Usually, for any integer power, it is common to write $\tan^n(x)$ instead of $(\tan(x))^n$. If this is the case, then $\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{\tan(x)}$

However, there is a very annoying habit in some part of the community in which the term $\tan^{-1}$ actually refers to the $\arctan$.

Personally, I find it very annoying when $\tan^{-1}$ is used to denote the inverse function instead of the power.

Comment: This is bad notation for the additional reason that it emulates the usual inverse notation $\cdot^{-1}$ for functions but does not actually define a (two-sided) inverse of $\tan$---of course no such inverse exists, as $\tan$ is not injective.

Comment: @Travis Indeed. It is bad notation that causes confusion where there would be none otherwise, and on top of it all, it gives false ideas about functions.

Comment: It's an annoyingly bad habit reinforced by those *$&^#**(@ calculators so many high school students have and that use that notation. Apparently, the good people from HP, TI, Casio, etc. think HS students are stupid and will be baffled by a notation like "arcsin" or, if space is an issue, by **at least*  "asin, acos, atan", etc.

Comment: @Timbuc - indeed, I remember now my old school calculator has that notation.

Comment: @5xum - thanks for the answer, in my case it turns out to be the arctan. I ran through some numbers on Woolfram Alpha and it gives me the results I was expecting.

Comment: @timbuc I remember those. My calculater had asin written on it, so I guess I was lucky.

Comment: I don't find it annoying to write $\tan^{-1}(x)$ instead of $\arctan(x)$. We also use the notation $f^{-1}(x)$ very frequently. Just be aware if you see $\tan^{-1}(x)$. It is never used to express $\frac{1}{\tan(x)}$ in handbooks!

Comment: @StevenVanGeluwe Yes, we use the notation $f^{-1}$, but we use it on bijective functions to mark the inverse of the function. $\tan$ is **not** bijective, and $\arctan$ is **not** its inverse.

Comment: The notation $\;f^{-1}\;$ can also be annoyingly confusing: it can mean the inverse function or the inverse image of a set.

Comment: Well @5xum In fact $\;\arctan\;$ **is** the inverse of $\;\tan x\;$ when this last one's domain is reduced to an open interval of length $\;\pi\;$ not containing any odd integer multiple of $\;\dfrac\pi2\;$ , usually $\;\left(-\dfrac\pi2,\,\dfrac\pi2\right)\;$ That is done with quite a few functions in order to *force* them to be bijerctive there and thus having an inverse there.

Comment: @Timbuc But it is clear that if $f:A\to B$, then $f^{-1}(x)$ means a preimage if $x$ is a subset of $B$ and it means the inverse function if $x$ is an element of $B$. The two different meanings cannot be confused because they can be understood from context.

Comment: @5xum Apparently not always, as there had been questions about this in this site.

Comment: @Timbuc Okay, yes, I agree, the $f^{-1}$ notation is not perfect. However, with careful use, it's possible to avoid almost all potentially confusing situations. The $\arctan = \tan^{-1}$ notation, however, is beyond redemption.